# Is AWS Route 53 Latency based routing applicable between different availibility zones of a same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I have multiple route53 records pointing to ECS instances in different AZs. I'm using a distributed DB that has some latency in replicating cross-AZ. For this reason, I would like for when my services call themselves, that it be an instance in the same availibity zone. AFAIK Latency based routing seems to not have the sufficient level of granularity. I've been suggested to use distinct Load Balancers for the different zones, but since this requires some heavy lifting I would like to know if there are any other options to force same-AZ calls.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up writing all our data on the same DC, using the nodes on the other DC as a fallback, so data is always read in the same zone as it is written.